# Error debugging Errai app in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, errai

When I try to debug an Errai app in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
 [WARN] Failed startup of context org.jboss.errai.cdi.server.gwt.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload@a9acff{/,/home/matthew/git/PressGangCCMSUI/src/main/webapp}
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Interestingly running mvn gwt:debug does allow me to run the application, even while this error exists in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specific cause, but when the project is cleaned, I can't run it in debug mode in Eclipse. To fix that I run the project with

```
mvn gwt:run
```

and once that launcher has come up I can then run the project in debug in Eclipse again.